# Xampp Intl extension on windows 10 can't be installed

Tags: php, magento, xampp, windows-10, intl

I try to install Megento 2 on Xampp (php 7.2.5) and through installation process I find Intl extension installation error

[image]

I did every thing `;extension=intl` to be `extension=intl` in php.ini

also I copied all files `icu*.dll` files from `xampp/php` to `xampp/php/ext` and to `xampp/apache/pin` directories and of course I restart Apache.

[image]

also download `MSVCP110.dll` and paste it to `C:\Windows\System32`

also checked PHP path in system variables and it is OK.

but until now the Intl extension never work

any help?

Comment: tbf, I'm not sure how well M2 runs on Windows, got it set up once and was slower than anything, killing my machine. Better to set up a Linux VM (not an answer- hence the comment)

Comment: Can you put your phpinfo() list?

Comment: @JohnCho what is list?

Comment: @Gouda Elalfy, please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: dear @JohnCho I know phpinfo() but what is the list, do you want the full page output?

Comment: do you have problem while running `composer install` ?

Comment: @ewwink yes, it was give me error that php_intl.dll doesn't exist or invalid 32 application, I tried to run composer to get the error but it doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: do you have Visual C++ 2015 x86 installed?

Comment: yes, recently installed when installing odoo system

Comment: thank you @ewwink it works now, after I restart apache, so the problem in Visual C++?

Comment: yes, in my system intl require this

Comment: can I add my answer below ? :D

Comment: Of course yes, but set all steps because i will not try or test, so be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xampp setup filename is contain `VCXX` for example `xampp-win32-7.2.5-0-VC15-installer.exe`, VC15 mean that PHP compiled with Visual Studio 2017, so you need to install `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017` to make PHP and Extensions running smoothly, but sometime already installed VC14 or `Visual C++ Redistributable 2015` is enough.

You can view list and download Visual C++ Redistributable [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Answer (score 5):

> Internationalization extension (further is referred as Intl) is a wrapper for » ICU library, enabling PHP programmers to perform various locale-aware operations including but not limited to formatting, transliteration, encoding conversion, calendar operations - http://php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php

For Windows-based Server:

Make sure the php_intl.dll file exists within your php extensions directory

- for separately installed PHP: C:\path\to\php\ext\
- for xampp: C:\path\to\xampp\php\ext
- (note: your drive letter might be different)

If the file exists:

- search for the config file (php.ini, usually in the same folder as the php executable) and open it. You can find this easy by running php --ini
- Make sure the line “extension=php_intl.dll” is existing and not commented
- Restart the web server (usually apache)
- Check if the extension is enabled using phpinfo(), or run `php - me` in cmd

If the file doesn’t exist:

- Check your php version by running the “php -v” command
- Download the PHP version that corresponds to yours from the PHP Downloads Page (TS/NTS, x86/x64)
- - To find thread safety for php, run: `php -i | findstr “Thread”` , The version that comes with xampp is usually `Thread Safety => enabled`.
- Search for the php_intl.dll file in the ext folder in that version and copy it in your php\ext folder
- Complete the steps for the case in which the file exists above.

---

Trouble shooting

Some web servers are confusing because they do not use the php.ini located alongside your PHP executable. To find out where your actual php.ini resides, look for its path in phpinfo(): or in cmd run `php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

After activating an extension, save php.ini, restart the web server and check phpinfo() again. The new extension should now have its own section.

If the extension does not appear in phpinfo(), you should check your logs to learn where the problem comes from.

If you are using PHP from the command line (CLI), the extension loading error can be read directly on screen.

If you are using PHP with a web server, the location and format of the logs vary depending on your software. Please read your web server documentation to locate the logs, as it does not have anything to do with PHP itself.

Common problems are the location of the DLL, the value of the " extension_dir" setting inside php.ini and compile-time setting mismatches.

If the problem lies in a compile-time setting mismatch, you probably didn't download the right DLL. Try downloading again the extension with the right settings. Again, phpinfo() can be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

You need change in [intl] section in php.ini file -

**Change below section**

*________________________________*

[intl]

;intl.default_locale =

; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error

; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.

; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.

;intl.error_level = E_WARNING

;intl.use_exceptions = 0

*____________________________________*

**To**

*________________________________*

[intl]

intl.default_locale = en_utf8

; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error

; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.

; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.

intl.error_level = E_WARNING

;intl.use_exceptions = 0

*____________________________________*

Comment: I did, but the same result